# Cloudfront mp4 not playing on some Android and iPhone browsers

Tags: html, video, amazon-cloudfront, mp4

I created an AWS Cloudfront distribution for my mp4 files hosted on S3. The Cloudfront distribution points to the S3 origin of the mp4 files.

I have an HTML5 website that plays these mp4 files in the code but I noticed that some of the mp4 files did not play on certain Android and iPhone devices.

When I tried opening the Cloudfront URL for the mp4 files that were not playing, the result was the same; so the problem might not be in my HTML5 video code, it might be some mp4 files could be incompatible with certain devices.

For testing purposes following are two URLs for mp4 files hosted on Cloudfront, the first one works on all browser versions (Desktop, Android, iPhone). The second one works on

1).http://djkvzdnel0qlh.cloudfront.net/prepare_booster/2+AUDIO+Prepare+Booster/EventPrep_M01_P01.mp4

Works on:

- Desktop browsers
- Android browsers
- iPhone browsers

2).http://djkvzdnel0qlh.cloudfront.net/explore_support/3+AUDIO+Explore+Support/stress/AAA_MS_BF_SET_1145.mp4

Works on:

- iPhone 5S - iOS ver 12.1.4 - Safari browser.
- iPhone 6S: - iOS ver 12.1.4 - Safari browser.
- iPhone X
- Newer iPad Mini - iOS ver 12.1 - Safari browser.
- Newer iPad Mini - updated to iOS ver 12.1.4 - Safari browser.
- Older Full Size iPad - iOS ver 9.3.5 (up to date for this unit)
- Very old iPod Touch - iOS ver 9.3.5 (up to date for than unit) - Safari browser.

DOES NOT work on:

- Samsung A5 - Android 8.0.0 - Firefox, Samsung browser, Chrome tested
- iPhone XS
- iPhone XS Max
- iPhone XR

Need help to know why I am having problems with the second mp4 file. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the second video a resolution of at least, say, 80x60.